# SwiftUI XCTestCase - Cell never become hittable

Tags: ios, swiftui, xctest, ios14, xctestcase

I'm trying to execute a XCTestCase where I have a list of elements. In this case my cell exists and it passes the first XCTAssertTrue, but is never hittable and when enter inside the while cycle it never come out. Any solutions? Thanks.

```
fileprivate func openDetailViewForAttendant(_ attendantBusinessName: String) {
    let cell = app.tables.staticTexts[attendantBusinessName]
    XCTAssertTrue(cell.waitForExistence(timeout: 3))
    
    while !cell.isHittable {
        app.swipeUp()
    }
    
    cell.tap()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for this question, as I also faced this problem.

**Solution**: **This happens when cell is scrolled below or above the screen.
That's why it's not hittable. So this is old bug in iOS.**

Basically this happens with **low resolution devices. So test on large resolution devices**.

Comment: Thank you, I've just tried to run my app on a physically device and the problem is solved.

Comment: You are welcome Sir, Could you please give me a upvote so that keep helping.